# android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED not available

Tags: android, sms, listener

I'm trying to create a new SMS receive listner.

I have googled the problem and all I found was it requires

android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED

but it doesnt exist in android 2.2

how to listen to new incoming messages is my question.!

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION that corresponds to string value android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED.

```
public static final String SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION =
                "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
```

Check out this question on how to do it: [BroadcastReceiver + SMS_RECEIVED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973071/broadcastreceiver-sms-received)

Answer (score 1):

I am using this to register this broadcast

```
IntentFilter f=new IntentFilter();
    f.addAction(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION);
    this.registerReceiver(c, f);
```

or 2nd way could be as of below.

by the way u are doing and don't forget using android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED as a string "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" as it's a intent through which you are receiving SMS.

and both approaches working on minsdk 19 and (target can be >=26).

```
IntentFilter f=new IntentFilter();
    f.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    this.registerReceiver(c, f);
```