# How to get a broadcast when an sms is sent by some app?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have implemented a Broadcast Receiver to receive intent android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT, but it does not seem to be working.
Basically, I want to get a notification when an sms is sent from phone by any "app".
Is there any other intent I should look for or is there a way to get some log info when an sms is sent by some app?

Answer (score 0):

According to an answer on this similar question, this may not be available:
[What is the Android sent sms intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116330/what-is-the-android-sent-sms-intent)

But you can do something similar if your app is the one sending the message using this technique:
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android