# listen for changes in Android sent sms other than monitoring the change in content://sms

Tags: android, sms

I'm looking into the possibilities of monitoring the sms sent from the device.

From the reading, I found out one of the way is through monitoring the change in content://sms.  This method works as expected.

However, from the experiment, I found out that some of the sms sent is not saved automatically in the database making the above method unusable.

Is there any other way or example that I can look into, for example using the `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT` ?

Comment: are you sending the SMS from code you wrote or are you interested in being notified when the default message client is used to send a SMS?

Answer (score 0):

If android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT is the correct intent you should be able to setup a broadcast receiver similar to this:

```
<receiver android:name="com.yourpackage.SomeClass"
    android:enabled="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

EDIT: 
having searched around some more the above may not work, it looks like there may not be a good way of doing what you want, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116330/what-is-the-android-sent-sms-intent) for more discussion.

Comment: Thank you.. yes i already read the link that you posted but I'm unable to find the sample code that specifically implemented this method everywhere.. most examples concentrated on polling content://sms/ approach