# Android default SMS app Send Event

Tags: android

In our Android app when a button is clicked we show the default SMS app with a phone number and a message set there. The code for that looks like this. Now when the user click on the send button in the default Messaging app, is there a way to catch that event. I want to know when the user click the send button. How can I catch that in my code?

```
String uri = "smsto:" + smsNumber;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(uri));
intent.putExtra("sms_body", SMSMessage);
intent.putExtra("compose_mode", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116330/what-is-the-android-sent-sms-intent

Comment: Thanks drees.But that's not working anymore