# Receiving SMS in Android Honeycomb

Tags: android, sms

Is it possible to send and receive SMS messages in Honeycomb?  The `android.telephony.SmsManager` class has methods for sending SMS, but there is no mention of how to receive.

It appears `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` was to be used for this purpose, but is no longer available.

Comment: @ntaj: I am not aware of any Honeycomb tablet that supports SMS at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED not available!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760212/android-provider-telephony-sms-received-not-available)

Comment: @CommonsWare Is it the Honeycomb platform itself that prevents SMS support, or is it more a matter of an app not existing for sending and receiving SMS?

Comment: @ntaj: Honeycomb tablets are not phones and do not offer any form of telephony beyond mobile data support.

Comment: @CommonsWare Have the telephony APIs been explicitly disabled in Honeycomb? I ask because it appears some tablets, such as the Xoom, are able to receive SMS messages. Have these vendors (Motorola in this case) written their own code to enable SMS listening?

Comment: @ntaj: "I ask because it appears some tablets, such as the Xoom, are able to receive SMS messages." -- and your proof of this is... what, exactly? Please do not point me to people with modded ROMs, rooted XOOMs, and the like. Bear in mind that the device fails the `android.hardware.telephony` `<uses-feature>` test (http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/02/25/xoom-permissions-android-market.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for that link and the info. Would you be able to point me to additional reading regarding Honeycomb and telephony operations? I'm just not clear **why** SMS is not supported. Is it a decision made by Google, and thus Honeycomb does not have an API for SMS; or have the manufacturers (such as Motorola) chosen not to implement it as they don't want their tablets to compete with their cell phones?

Comment: @ntaj: "I'm just not clear why SMS is not supported." -- generally, "why" questions like that have no known definitive answer.