# How to update the settings Through SMS

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am developing one GPS based application. in that i given few default values to user those are phone number which will used to make a phone call. and server address which is used to sent the location data to server.. In this I got 2 major and critical problems..

1) I have hide that default values in regular menu and that should display when user presses some key or combination of keys then only it should display.

2)When ever the Default phone number and server address is changed at provider side that should be updated at user side that should happen through SMS from a specific number in a encrypted format by accepting that SMS those values has to change

Please Any body knows about these things help which are very very very useful to me

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

[Lots of good info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973071/broadcastreceiver-sms-received).

Having used SMSes to communicate with apps in the past, I highly recommend finding another way if possible. The messages coming in are often gibberish to the user, and practically never contain any information that the user needs to know about. They're confusing and they clutter up the user's phone experience.

I'd recommend using WAP pushes or periodic device-side checks instead. If you have to use SMSes, you may want to consider using the SMS content provider to delete the messages after your application responds to them. It'll still be annoying to the user, but at least you won't be leaving behind garbage in their messaging app. Be aware though that the SMS/MMS content providers aren't published, which means that they're not guaranteed to work, manufacturers can modify them however they want, and they could be phased out in a future SDK release.

Comment: Thanks for Your valuable reply,

Comment: But, My client needs that functionality only

Comment: Did you check out the link? There are details there for how to register for SMS messages and process them when received. Have your app register for SMS messages. When a message from the predetermined phone number comes in you can read its text and react accordingly.

Comment: I checked that link, but i dis not get any idea to send the Updates in a encrypted format to the user.. when he accepts that SMS then the settings of the application should change that is my requirement.. help me in this if you have any idea.. thanks for reading

Comment: Sorry, I thought your question was about how to read incoming SMSes. For encryption you can use any number of open source encryption algorithms. http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/package-summary.html is a good place to start.To send the SMS from your server you'll need a messenging provider and the exact method for sending the SMS will depend upon their API.