# How to navigate android doc for specific intent?

Tags: android, navigation

I have been using flex for couple of years but I am new to android. I know about activities, receivers and services.

I need some help related to navigation in android doc.

How can I find out in documentation about the intents being fired related to a particular class and what are the details of that particular intent.

Let me clarify my question by giving you an example. 
I wanted to know how can I receive a new sms. I knew that I have to listen for some intent in a broadcast receiver and some permissions have to be added in manifest file. I went to the docs and looked for some intent in `android.telephony.SmsManager` but I was unable to find it.
So by searching on the net I found that "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" is the intent which I will receive in broadcast receiver. 
How can I find the detail about this particular event in android docs?
What this intent contains, who fires this? What is contained in the bundle?

I think intents are similar to events in flex. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973071/broadcastreceiver-sms-received/1973931#1973931

Comment: I don't just want to know the intent detail of SMS_RECEIVED. I am talking about all the Intents.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i find out in documentation about the intents being fired related to a particular class and what are the details of that particular intent.

Intents are not really "related to a particular class". Details of a particular `Intent` action are documented on that action. To find where the action is documented, search on its name in http://developer.android.com.

> I wanted to know how can i receive a new sms.
>   ...
>   How can i find the detail about this particular event in android docs? What this intent contains, who fires this? What is contained in the bundle?

Technically speaking, this is undocumented and should not be used. In practice, it is so widely used that Google would be insane to change its behavior. However, you will not find official documentation on this subject.

> I think intents are similar to events in flex. Is this understanding correct?

Insofar as they both involve computers, yes, they are similar. :-)

It has been a few years since I used Flex, but IIRC, Flex events are closer to Android widget listeners (e.g., `setOnClickListener()`).

Comment: i have already tried searching SMS_RECEIVED in android docs but all u get is the reference in one of the samples and intent filters topic. Shouldn't the documentation contain what is contained in a particular intent and what are different intents available?

Comment: @Haris Sarwar: `SMS_RECEIVED` is technically not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: Then where is the reference material for it?

Comment: @Haris Sarwar: THERE IS NO REFERENCE MATERIAL FOR IT. This is the point that I have been making, repeatedly. It is not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: I got you point that Android SDK doesn't contain the details of different intents and that is why i am unable to find it in the documentation.

Comment: @Haris Sarwar: Documented `Intent` actions are, by definition, documented. You find them in the documentation, typically by searching, examining the `Intent` class (easily more than half are documented there), or a likely other candidate class (classes ending in `Manager` in an `android.*` package will sometimes have documented `Intent` actions). But in a case where you run into an action and cannot find it in the docs by searching, it is undocumented, and its use is risky. Undocumented things are subject to change at whim by Google and device manufacturers.

Comment: @Haris Sarwar: You are welcome to check out the Intent Registry at openintents.org, though they do not necessarily distinguish what is and is not documented/supported.

Comment: But my real intention with reference material was that besides android doc is there any other documentation which contains these details or an android developer would always have to find such details through forums?