# Callback when another ContentProvider's data changes

Tags: android

let's say I want to know when a contact on the device gets deleted... Or an SMS message, or something from the call log.
Is there a way to receive a callback or a broadcast for this kind of event, without polling and comparing all the time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for the appropriate broadcast `Intent` such as `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` for SMS.

[This other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973071/broadcastreceiver-sms-received) question has some code for doing so.