# can broadcast receveir work even when my app is closed

Tags: android

I am building a simple sms app , i want to open my app automaticaly when ever a new sms is received? is **it even possible?**
i am using broadcast receiver for this

what changes should i made in manifest?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.message"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Reply" >
    </activity>
 </application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: I think it should work if you are adding the receiver at the Manifest level and not at the Activity level(Using code).

Comment: how exactly can i do that shashank?? i am a newbee in android

Comment: I have this problem too. my receiver is out of activity level but when app is closed, it wont recived any thing after opened with notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should move the receiver outside from the activity  like this:

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Reply" >
    </activity>
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
 </application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Under Android 3.0 and later, your broadcast is not guaranteed to be received unless the user has opened your application. The application does not have to remain opened, just to have been started once. This is caused by a flag ([FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES)) which is now part of most system broadcasts, which says the broadcast should not start a stopped application.

Comment: ya , it works some times (1 aut of 20 raughly) . BTW can u ply tell me what can i do now??

Answer (score 0):

This was already answered in [How to make android launch an application on received specific sms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433488/how-to-make-android-launch-an-application-on-received-specific-sms) to keep it short: it is possible with BroadcastReceiver.