# What is happening in Android when i run Thread.sleep in background service

Tags: android, multithreading

What is happening in Android if I have IntentService defined as following:

```
public class BackgroundService  extends IntentService {
    public BackgroundService() {
        super("BackgroundService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
        run();
    }
    private void run() {
        try {
            while(true)
            {
                //Some expensive Internet & SQL querying stuff
                Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 60);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How bad will it drain the battery?
I aim for rather fundamental answer (What will happen if I set the sleep to 1 day)?

Comment: Your service can remain running but without doing any work, without the need to call Thread.sleep, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Philio Well, as far as the multithreading environment is concerned I suppose that if I put my thread to sleep I give other threads the resources that I do not necessarily need.

Comment: As @A--C said, just let it exit when it's done processing the intent.

Comment: I understand that this is an anti pattern to use the service like this. But what should I do if I need to notify user about some time-based events (such as upcoming lessons) and I expect that user is going to install my app and "never" open it again because he is notified by the Android status bar notifications?

Comment: @VojtěchBašta You would use `AlarmManager` + accompanying `BroadcastReceiver`(s) for time-based events. Generating a status bar notification takes virtually no time, but if your SQL & internet queries take up more than 10 seconds, you'll probably have to make the `BroadcastReceiver` acquire `Wakelock` and start a `Service` that does the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question to so close to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789531/thread-and-battery-consumption). He also trying to do some work inside a loop and make the Thread sleep.

From the Geeks answer in the provided question, I can tell you that it depends on the `//Some code` line and what will you replace it with. You might replace it with an intensive code that use the internet, GPS, Flash, Camera and consume your battery for sure **OR** you might replace it with nothing and let the `Thread` sleep which allow the `CPU` to replace it with any other `Thread` that needs to perform anything.

Comment: Question updated. I do some expensive internet and SQL operations. I this is the case, does this change anything? If so why would it?

Comment: The answer is **YES** it will consume battery charges for sure. You can make sure of this by opening the `settings` of your device and select from the `LeftMenu` Battery to see how your device resources can consume the battery level :)

Comment: So if I have Sleep for 1 day it will drain the battery even during the sleep time?

Comment: It depends on how frequently you are repeating the action that drain the battery. If you did you `Internet and SQLite` actions only once a day will not be the same as repeating it 200 times per day